# Flare edit vertices with keyframes

Tags: animation

How do I use keyframes with the 'Edit vertices' option on Flare by 2Dimensions?

My use-case: I want to animate a rectangle by just transforming it into a different shape by dragging the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Click on 'Convert to path' in the right-side panel. Then you will be able to edit vertices just as you would with any other property like size or position.